# Typo in today's podcast - Github should be GitHub

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, podcast, capitalization

If you notice [How an average programmer became Github’s CTO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/31/jason-warner-cto-github-redpoint-ventures-web3/?cb=1), both the title and the body of the post have *Github* written with only one capital letter while the usual styling of the name should be *GitHub* with the *H* capitalized.

The linked post is currently featured on SO, Code Golf, Code Review, etc... So the typo is having considerable visibility within the coding community.

Comment: An alternative would be using the commenting system on the blog (and observing [the caveats wrt. JavaScript blocking](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/06/24/formatting-wordpress-comments-e-g-on-the-stack-overflow-official-blog/)). What is the preferred and/or effective mechanism?

Comment: Blog vs MSE for blog corrections probably should be a question on its own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of the podcast embedded in the [linked blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/31/jason-warner-cto-github-redpoint-ventures-web3/) is now fixed; the typo in the blog post title was fixed earlier. They both now read:

> How a very average programmer became GitHub's CTO

The capitalization issue has been fixed in a few other places as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: While we're at it, there's another typo in the body of the blog post:

[image]

> [...] goes to dfrib for **suggestion** a solution to [...]

Here, ["suggestion" should be "suggest**ing**"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1kBM.png).

---

Apart from the incorrect casing in the title of the *podcast*, there's another typo before "very":

[image]

The title of the *blog post* does not have this typo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Both these issues should be fixed as well.